# How do I convert MKZoomScale to a standard [0-20] zoom level?

Tags: ios, mapkit

I'd like to write some drawing rules inside `drawMapRect:zoomScale:inContext:` based on the standard [0-20] zoom levels that mapping platforms like Google Maps use, but I can't seem to find a formula to convert MKZoomScale to that scale. Any takers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this category on MKMapView

```
@interface MKMapView (Additions)
- (double)zoomLevel;
@end


@implementation MKMapView (Additions)

- (double)zoomLevel {
    double totalTilesAtMaxZoom = MKMapSizeWorld.width / 256.0;
    NSInteger zoomLevelAtMaxZoom = log2(totalTilesAtMaxZoom);

    return MAX(0, zoomLevelAtMaxZoom + log2f(self.zoomScale));
}

@end
```

Comment: Does that still hold true for you on iOS13?